# how to convertfrom long to String

Tags: java, android, arrays, typecasting-operator

Hi i'm trying to convert long value into String but getting error 
    `Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to String`

This is the block of code please have a look

```
URLConnection localURLConnection = new URL("http://hugosys.in/SQLite/sk2.db").openConnection();
int i = localURLConnection.getContentLength();
BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = new     BufferedInputStream(localURLConnection.getInputStream());
ByteArrayBuffer localByteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);
FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Download_Db.this.dbFile);
long l = 0L;
for (;;)
{
int j = localBufferedInputStream.read();
if (j == -1)
{
localFileOutputStream.flush();
localFileOutputStream.close();
return;
}
l += j;
localByteArrayBuffer.append((byte)j);
if (localByteArrayBuffer.length() > 2000)
{
byte[] arrayOfByte = localByteArrayBuffer.toByteArray();
localByteArrayBuffer.clear();
String[] arrayOfString = new String[1];
arrayOfString[0] = (l / i);
publishProgress(arrayOfString);
localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte);

}
}
return;
```

Comment: String s = "" + longValue;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to use the Java API

```
long longValue = 42l;
String stringValue = String.valueOf(longValue);
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(long))

Answer (score 2):

You are storing `long` value in a `String[]`.

so chnage this line

```
arrayOfString[0] = (l / i);
```

into

```
arrayOfString[0] = String.valueOf(l / i);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
arrayOfString[0] = String.valueOf((l / i))

Answer (score 1):

You can use   String.valueOf(longValue).

As per your code you have to use

```
arrayOfString[0] = (l / i);
```

replace with

`arrayOfString[0] = String.valueOf((l / i));`// converts long to String

Answer (score 0):

```
    String.valueOf(longValue);// converts long to String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = String.valueOf(longValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert long value to String

```
String val= String.valueOf(longVal);
```

So in your code **replace arrayOfString[0] = (l / i)** with this:

```
arrayOfString[0] =String.valueOf (l / i);
```